# How to swap objects using array, C++ . I want to chane

Tags: c++, arrays

I have done the following code to swap my 4 objects which are clothes, pants, shoes and toiletries. I want each of my object to save the data of the properties. But there are too many errors eventhough I have corrected it many times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
class MySuitcase // Class
{
    // Declare all the propertie used for the items.
    public:
        int quantity; 
        int size;
        int colour;
        double weight;
        double volume;
        char name;

    MySuitcase () // Constructor
    {
        quantity = 0;
        size = 0;
        colour = 0;
        weight = 0.0;
        volume = 0.0;
    }
    // Constructor for items name
    MySuitcase (char name_given ) 
    {   
        name = name_given;
    }
    // Function prototype
    void swap ();
    void items_name();
};
    // Swap Function
    void swap ()
    {   
        int temp;
        int Suitcase[j];

        temp = Suitcase[j];
        Suitcase[j] =  Suitcase[i];
        Suitcase[i] = temp;
    }
    // List of item on display
    void items_name()
    {
        string Suitcase[5];

        Suitcase[0]="Clothes";
        Suitcase[1]="Pants";
        Suitcase[2]="Shoes";
        Suitcase[3]="Toiletries";
        Suitcase[4]="Total volume & weight of suitcase.";

    }

    void Propmt_CLothes()
    {   int Suitcase;
        for (i=0; i<6; i++)
            cout << " Please input the quantity: ";
            cin >> Clothes[i].quantity;
            cout << " Please input the weight: ";
            cin >> Clothes[i].weight;
            cout << " Please input the volume: ";
            cin >> Clothes[i].volume;
            cout << " Please input the size: ";
            cin >> Clothes[i].size;
            cout << " Please input the colour: ";
            cin >> Clothes[i].colour;
    }


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    MySuitcase Suitcase[5];

    MySuitcase Suitcase[0] = new Suitcase(Clothes);
    // Display initial list of items
    cout << " This is the list of items for your suitcase: \n";
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        MySuitcase().items_name();
        cout << i << " - "<< Suitcase[i] << endl;
    }
    // Prompt user to choose items for swapping
    cout << " Please choose 2 items you want to swap: \n";
    cin >> i, j;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are many errors in your code. Your swap function is the least of your worries. You don't seem to understand variable scope or function arguments. I'm not trying to be rude. Start much smaller and solve the errors as you go, until you work up to this example.

Comment: first of all see the scope of variables and youa re using char to store the name , first correct them , and explain your requirement correctly

Comment: Your variable declaration is not good (scope variable). What error you got ?

Answer (score 1):

1 - You should declare any variable witch you use like `j` in this function `swap`:

```
// Swap Function
void swap ()
{   // what are i and j
    int temp;
    int Suitcase[j];

    temp = Suitcase[j];
    Suitcase[j] =  Suitcase[i];
    Suitcase[i] = temp;
}
```

And like the `i` int the `for-loop` `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)` and add the `{}` to execute all instructions in the for-loop 
like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    cout << " Please input the quantity: ";
   // ...
}
```

2 - You have errors to create an array of abject(Suitecase). You should declare it like this:

```
MySuitcase Suitcase[6]; // in Main method
```

3 - Don't forget to also declare variables before use it :

```
int i, j;
cin >> i, j;
```

4 - Declaration of array in

```
void Propmt_CLothes() {
    MySuitcase Clothes[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << " Please input the quantity: ";
        cin >> Clothes[i].quantity;
        cout << " Please input the weight: ";
        cin >> Clothes[i].weight;
        cout << " Please input the volume: ";
        cin >> Clothes[i].volume;
        cout << " Please input the size: ";
        cin >> Clothes[i].size;
        cout << " Please input the colour: ";
        cin >> Clothes[i].colour;
    }
}
```

And many other error. You should read [the C++ doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/)

Comment: what is i ?? and why is he swapping an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a few misunderstandings about C++.

- [Variable Scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) defines "where" a variable lives. When you create a variable in one place, it's not always accessible elsewhere in your code.

For example:

```
void foo(){
   int a = 0;
}

void bar(){
   int b = 1;
}
```

`a` is not accessible in `bar`, and `b` is not accessible in `foo`. This is because the variables only live within the scope of the function. Hit up the link to learn more.

- [Functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) in C++ take arguments

```
void swap(int& a, int& b){
   int tmp = a;
   a = b;
   b = tmp;
}
```

You can only modify globally accessible variables (See scope), or those variables passed into or declared inside a function. Here, our `swap` function takes 2 `ints` and swaps their values. The `int`s are given to the function as parameters (also called arguments)

Hit up those links, and use that knowledge to correct your code. You'll see that declaring `Suitcase

- In C++, you access [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) values a bit differently than you are trying to, for example

`int Suitcase[j];`

Does not get the j<sup>th</sup> element of `Suitcase`. In fact, this statement makes no sense at all. Read up on creating and accessing arrays to learn more.

Read up more on these topics, and then revisit your code. You will hopefully see that you are improperly attempting to express yourself in C++, and can correct it (without any help from us!)